# Autofac - resolve services by generic interface

Tags: autofac

Let's have the following code

```
public class Handler : IHandle<ICommentInfo>{}

public class Command1 : ICommentInfo{}

public interface ICommentInfo{}

public interface IHandle<T> where T : class{}
```

I'd like to resolve the service like this

```
var service = c.Resolve<IHandle<Command1>>();
```

Is this even possible ?

I tried this configuration

```
 builder.RegisterType<Handler>().As<IHandle<ICommentInfo>>();
```

But I'm getting this exception

```
The requested service 'Icp.Test.QuerySpec.Class1+IHandle`1[[Icp.Test.QuerySpec.Class1+Command1, Icp.Test.QuerySpec, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does you do not want to use

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<LocalCommand>().As(typeof (ICommentInfo));
builder.RegisterType<Handler>().As(typeof(IHandle<ICommentInfo>));
var c = builder.Build();
var handler = c.Resolve<IHandle<ICommentInfo>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bulider.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());
```

Switches on this behaviour.